# Splitting list in Python if two elements are next to each other

Tags: python, list, data-structures

how can i split a list based on neighboring elements, so if i have a list such as

`test = [3,5,7,1,10,17]`

and i want to split the list if element 10 and 17 are next to each other so that the split happens between `[3,5,7,1]` and `[10,17]`.

I know there is groupby but i could only figure out how to use that to check if one element is present and then split, but not two after each other.

pseudocode:

```
for i in list:
      if element[i] == 10 and element[i+1] == 17:
                  splitlist() # split before elements 10
```

Comment: what happens to elements after 17?

Comment: @enke the split should happen before the first element to check essentially, so in this case before element 10. And the elements after 17 should just stay in the list, only elements before 10 should be separated into a list

Comment: Traverse list, use arr[:n] to slice it? Is there a problem with that approach?

Comment: What is the logic behind the neighbor splitting? You have to tell us that so we can help you. The 5 if next to 7 also, why it wasn't splitted?

Comment: @dsenese added some pseudocode to help understand the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip()` the list with an offset of itself to get pairs. Then find the index of the pair you are looking for (assuming this happens once or you only care about the first). Then splice the list:

```
test = [3,5,7,1,10,17]

def partition_on_pair(test, pair):
    index = next((i for i, n in enumerate(zip(test, test[1:])) if n == pair), len(test))
    return test[:index], test[index:]

partition_on_pair(test, (10, 17))
# ([3, 5, 7, 1], [10, 17])

partition_on_pair(test, (10, 19)) # doesn't exist, so you get an empty
#([3, 5, 7, 1, 10, 17], [])


partition_on_pair(test, (5, 7))
#([3], [5, 7, 1, 10, 17])

partition_on_pair(test, (3,5))
#([], [3, 5, 7, 1, 10, 17])
```

Comment: exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example based on your output:

```
def split_list(test, match):
    idx = [test.index(i) for i in match]
    if sum([i - min(idx) for i in idx]) == sum(range(len(match))
        return [
            test[0:idx[0]],
            test[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1]
        ]

split_list(test=[3, 5, 7, 1, 10, 17], match=[10, 17])
```

Comment: This returns `None`:  `split_list(test=[3, 10, 5, 7, 1, 10, 17], match=[10, 17])`

Comment: Yeah, it will work only for his example, it's a cheap solution was just curious if it can be done with this sum  method

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working code:

```
test = [3,5,7,1,10,17]

def neighbor_splitting():
    for x in test:
        if x == 10:
            index = test.index(x)
            list1 = test[:index]
            list2 = test[index:]
            return list1, list2

# [3, 5, 7, 1]
# [10, 17]
```

Comment: What happens if test is `test = [3,10,5,7,1,10,17]`?

Comment: This will split into [3,10] and [5,7,1,10,17]. But the splitting logic was not very explained by the OP, so in the if statement he can put his logic.